# vimdiff - disable highlighting a particular line

Tags: vim, vi, vimdiff

I doing a code-review for a colleague. I have opened the diff using vimdiff. There are over 50 changes within the same file. Each line that has a diff is highlighted. Thus, I have close to 50 highlighted lines. As I work through the code review, I would like to mark the lines I have fully reviewed as OK. One way to do this, would be to tell vim to not highlight that line anymore. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You could use this:

```
highlight  Hignore ctermfg=black guifg=black                                                                                                   
command! D call matchadd("Hignore",getline('.'))
```

Typing `:D` will highlight the current line according to `Hignore`. To recover the original highlighting do `:call clearmatches()`.